# PrimeFaces Datatable looks different in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

In my application, the primeface datatable is looking different in IE and Firefox. In IE, it looks a bit unprofessional. Below you will find the attached screenshots.

IE:

[image: IE]
Firefox:

[image]

I checked Primeface's showcase and found that the default look in datatable is like that only.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableBasic.jsf;jsessionid=1qdz8fc102lqt16oiglwr9p6g8

But is it possible to do something with CSS Styling?

Answer (score -1):

Gradients are not supported in old versions of IE, at least not at the standard way. Check [this application](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). It will help you to generate CSS gradients that works on older versions of IE and also in IE9.

Comment: It's not the gradient I am looking for.